# Compare the addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There is the  field in my query called address. Now here is the requirement: If this address is equal to another field which contains the address the give some indication like (*)

For eg:

This the  field:
[address,city,state] which is concatenated using ,. address,city and state are different fields in the table. I have concatenated using ,. Now I want to verify that this entire field is equal to another field which contains address, city, state.

Can anyone give me some sample query

Comment: You want compare [address,city,state] separately with each columns?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then this should work for you:

```
Select * From AddressTable at Where at.Address + ',' + at.City + ',' + at.State = @YourVariable
```

If any of your variables are not text-based you'd need to cast before concatenating, as below:

```
Cast(Name as NVarChar(max))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the concatenated field is in the same table as the individual fields and that you are looking to see if the values match on a per record basis. If that's the case, then something like this

```
UPDATE [AddressTable] at
SET at.[Indicator] = '*'
WHERE at.[address,city,state] = at.[Address] + ',' + at.[City] + ',' + at.[State];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should be the solution:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AddressTable WHERE Address = a.Address) > 1 THEN '* ' + Address
    ELSE Address
  END
FROM AddressTable a
```